# Modify ggsurvplot (font.size) and type of confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survminer

I am trying to modify and better understand the way the function `ggsurvplot()` works (package: `survminer`):

First of all some code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(survival))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(survminer))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

set.seed(2020)

exp <- sample_n(lung, size = 10, replace = F) %>%
  select(time, status)

exp <- sample_n(lung, size = 10, replace = F) %>%
  select(time, status)

exp$survival <- Surv(exp$time, exp$status == 2)

exp_fit <- survfit(survival ~ 1, data = exp, conf.type = "log-log")

ggsurvplot(exp_fit,
           data = exp,
           palette = "black",
           censor.shape = "I",
           censor.size = 5.5,
           xlab = "days",
           ylab = "survival probability",
           conf.int = T,
           surv.scale = "percent",
           legend.title = "censored data",
           legend.lab = "",
           legend ="bottom")
```

The dataframe used is called `lung`. The data is contained in the package `survival`.

Basically I have two questions:

1. The plot prints confidence intervals as it should, BUT what type of them? Are they the same I specified within the `survfit()` function I used to create the object `exp_fit` and if not what needs to be the changed so that the same type of confidence intervals are used?
2. The font size of the legend is quite small. How can I make it bigger?
   I tried to work with `theme()`, but unfortunately it did not work.

I will appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For number 2, from here it looks like you can add `ggtheme = theme(...)` and produce your own theme elements. https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html

Comment: Hi cardinal40, thanks number 2 is solved. I added ggtheme = theme_pubr() to the plot. Now I am satisfied with the way that it looks. But I have still no clue which type of confidence intervals are shown.

Answer (score 2):

RE question 1

I was wondering the same thing and found this online:

"The function `ggsurvplot` inherits the chosen confidence interval from the `survfit` object."
[https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~vavraj/cda/exercise_04.html](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Evavraj/cda/exercise_04.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31006616)